# Skype4Py - Skype Bot - Greet New Joiners

Tags: python, skype4py

How do I make a function for Skype in my python script ( In use for Skype4py ) That greets new comers, and says good bye to those that leave, or get kicked?

Example, I know I need to have Event Handlers;
`OnChatMembersChanged(Chat, Members)` - Catches events of changing members in a chat

E.g;

```
OnChatMembersChanged
Get Method:
unreachable(self)
Set Method:
unreachable(self, Value)
```

But how do I integrate in my python script, e.x;

To give a certain idea of how my commands are implied, we've got the basic imports, and the commands are defined by

{ 
commands
listofcommands
Where !fml is typed, and is defined as commandFml with the response triggered in Skype seen below;

```
def commandFml(self,message):
            tit = urllib2.urlopen('http://m.fmylife.com/random').read()
            fml = getBetween(tit,'<p class="text">','</p>')
            message.Chat.SendMessage(strip_tags('/me '+fml))
```

How do I integrate where when members join, the bot acknowledges these changes, and greets them, and when they leave, the bot says good bye?

Comment: Please post the code you already wrote so that anyone can help you improve what you have already done.

Comment: Apologies, mate. I have most deff. done this.
Thank-you so much! (:
Now, to await an efficient response that I can deem an answer!